# How to serialize POCO Class to AVRO type using Newtonsoft.Json or other

Tags: c#, json, .net, serialization, avro

I need help in serializing POCO class to AVRO. How to create AVRO type using Netonsoft.Json can also be another serializer as long as it works on .NET framework 4.5.2 any ideas?

Comment: POJO stands for [Plain Old **Java** Object](https://www.baeldung.com/java-pojo-class). How do you plan to have a POJO in C#?

Comment: @PeterCsala sorry i mean POCO class

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45338832/can-a-c-sharp-model-be-serialized-as-an-avro-json-schema

Comment: @ChrisBD Microsoft.Hadoop.Avro not working for me

Comment: Maybe you need to install the NuGet package in your solution.

Comment: @ChrisBD if it was that simple ... makes solution on framework 4.5.2 and see for yourself that it doesn't work